# Setting CNAME for Azure website deployment slot

Tags: dns, azure

I have a Azure website (let's say `myapp.azurewebsites.net`) that has the main site + one "beta" deployment slot that I want to set up a CNAME record for. I'd like to set up `beta.myapp.com` to point to `myapp-beta.azurewebsites.net`, however I don't get the instructions in the Azure portal:

> To verify authorization, create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to myapp(beta).azurewebsites.net, or from awverify.www.yourdomain.com to awverify.myapp(beta).azurewebsites.net.

As far as my DNS-provider can tell me, parenthesis is not allowed in domain names, so `awverify.myapp(beta).azurewebsites.net` is not a valid domain to point to. I have also tried `awverify.myapp-beta.azurewebsites.net` without any luck.

Have anyone here successfully done this? If so, I would appreciate some pointers...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by going to the old portal. The correct CNAME is `awverify.beta.myapp.com => awverify.myapp-beta.azurewebsites.net`.